# Powershell fill in the path

Tags: powershell, ironpython

My current directory is "C:\devel\test\"

I would like to run something like `command -m 'pwd'\data\test.xml` and it act as though I entered `command -m C:\devel\test\data\test.xml`

If I were writing a script I would:

```
$pwd = pwd
command -m $pwd\data\test.xml
```

But not sure how to do this at the prompt.

**update**

This may be an IronPython issue. Using the command [azhrei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/360932/azhrei) suggested below `ipy -m ($pwd.path + "\data\test.xml")` I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 101, in _get_module_details
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\runpy.py", line 170, in run_module
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 456, in get_loader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 466, in find_loader
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\IronPython 2.7\Lib\pkgutil.py", line 422, in iter_importers
ImportError: Import by filename is not supported.
```

When I run `ipy -m C:\devel\test\data\test.xml` it works just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use %CD% at the command prompt, so:

`command -m %CD%\data\test.xml`

Or if you mean you're having problems at the powershell prompt:

`command -m ($pwd.path + "\data\test.xml")`

Comment: hmm. There may be an issue with IronPython then. When I run `ipy -m c:\devel\test\data\test.xml` it works when I run `ipy -m ($pws.path + "\data\text.xml")` it doesn't.

Comment: Given that you're passing a path in to the module option, and it is XML to boot, I'm puzzled how `ipy -m C:\devel\test\data\test.xml` can be working for you. I'm downloading ipy 2.7 to try it. :) Btw, do you have any earlier versions than ipy 2.7 installed as well?

Comment: WXP, Ipy 2.7.3, I get the same exception (/Import by filename is not supported/) as expected. The reason I asked if you have other versions installed is that some versions of python earlier than 2.6 had a bug in the -m option that allowed filenames.

Comment: @azheri - IronPython 2.7 2.7.0.40 on .NET 4.0.30319.1 is my current and only version. Just installed is the other day.

Comment: Happy to poke around if you can help me reproduce the case where it works for you. What does test.xml look like?

Comment: @azheri - Unfortunately I can't, the xml is all internal IP. I'll have to use a workaround.

Comment: This does in-fact append the strings, just not getting the results I was hoping for.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `join-path` cmdlet:

```
command -m "$(join-path $pwd 'data\test.xml')"
```

It will look after normalizing slashes etc.

Comment: I get the same `Unhandled exception:` listed above with this once as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
command -m "$pwd\data\test.xml"
```